# OMDB API: Any way to specify a *minimum* year on a movie title query?

Tags: api, imdb

I'm loving the OMDB API but one issue I'm having is that sometimes during a title query, an older movie will be returned instead of the one I'm looking for.

For example, there's a movie called "[Eye in the Sky](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2057392/)" coming out in 2016. But when I query `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=eye+in+the+sky&type=movie`, I get an older movie from 2007.

But I'm also not sure what the exact year is of the movie I'm looking for (only that it will be at least 2014). Is there any way to set a minimum year for this type of thing? How would you handle this?

Answer (score -2):

please use url as `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=eye+in+the+sky&type=movie&year=2016`, instead of `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=eye+in+the+sky&type=movie`.